# How to make migrations in zodb?

Tags: python, zodb, object-oriented-database

I can see in docs, that if I would change some fields in class then I need to write a migration script. But what exactly do I need to write in that script? Also is there a some automatic migration maker like there is in dgango?

Answer (score 1):

In your script you would modify the object stored in ZODB to match the new format of the object as your code requires.

No, there is no easy to use migration "maker".

Comment: How should I add/remove field in old objects? Should I use python reflection capabilities?

Comment: You should know what your old object looks like, and what your new object is going to look like in your script that is going to migrate the data.